Prevent auto create new database connection each request in Spring
I am using Spring with config:
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=100
I send stress test from client (400 concurrent request) and there is some errors:
Connection is not available, request timed out after 5047ms (total=100, active=100, idle=0, waiting=57)
Connection is not available, request timed out after 5047ms (total=100, active=100, idle=0, waiting=56)
Connection is not available, request timed out after 5047ms (total=100, active=100, idle=0, waiting=55)

Of course, those APIs throw SQL Exception (500).
Now I want to prevent create Connection when it exceeded 100. It should use one available Connection in pool.
I am looking for some config like:
spring.datasource.hikari.waiting_when_reached_max_connection=true

or
spring.datasource.hikari.use_available_when_reached_max_connection=true


Your threads ARE waiting for a connection once 100 are used but timing out after 5047ms. Are you setting this somewhere because the default is 30000ms? Anyway if you set spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout to a high enough setting it will wait until a connection becomes available.

@JohnWilliams yes, I change from 30000ms to 5000ms, but my queries is very fast (about 10ms/1 request). And Spring does not execute those queries like the queue did. When Spring receive more than 100 concurrent connections (this case is 400), 100 first connections successfully, but the query need wait 5000ms to be executed, and 300 others will be deny.

@JohnWilliams That mean, the first result return to client when more than 100 requests connection, will go in 5000ms (equals to timeout). That is a huge delay.

Yes, it’s taking so long because the DB is overloaded. To support this load the DB needs more resources.
